# How to display count in percentage for nominal data in power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Here is how my data file is structures

| Candidate | Month | Decision |
| --- | --- | --- |
| candidate-1 | Nov | Pass |
| candidate-2 | Nov | Fail |
| candidate-3 | Dec | Pass |

I import this file in power BI and I want to make a stacked bar with % of pass and fail for each month.

How can I achieve this?

I can get the count like this

| Month | Pass | Fail |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Nov | 20 | 4 |
| Dec | 12 | 2 |

But I need percentage, power BI has no option to display percentage on this data. I tried searching everywhere but no avail. Any help/pointer is highly appreciated.

Comment: Add custom columns showing the percent pass and percent fail for the month. Then graph those columns

Comment: If I add custom columns in table-2 (with pass/fail columns), everytime my dataset is changed, I have to do that manually. I want some way to do it automatically when data is changed. Isn't there any way to ask power BI to also give percentage while giving the numbers?

Comment: I don't understand.  If you change your dataset, how does Power BI update the existing Table 2?  Why can't you add the custom column as part of the query itself?

Comment: If I understand right, you habe to create a measure in Power-Bi. Take a Look to the DAX Function COUNTX() and COUNT() to calculate the Percentage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Actually, it was very simple. Power BI has 2 kinds of stacked bar - 1. Stacked bar based on count (this is what I was using) and 2. Stacked bar based on percent (this is what I needed but did not notice before).

I clicked on the chart and selected "100 stacked column chart" from the list of visuals and it is exactly what I expected it to be.

PS: I am new to power BI and it was nice adventure. Thank you @Ron Rosenfield and @Chris for your comments.